# Loading an ATF texture into a ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, arrays, stage3d

I'm trying to optimise the amount of GPU memory my textures use for a Stage3D project so I thought I'd finally switch to ATF textures. I've converted them from png to atf using the png2atf tool but once I load them into Flash (using URLLoader) I'm having trouble passing the resulting .data into ByteArrays. Here's what I have in my ImageLoader class:

```
private function loadImage():void {
    loader=new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadingError);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("assets/"+_imageStrings[_loadCounter])); // _imageStrings is an Array of string paths for each atf. _loadCounter increments with each successful atf load     
}

private function loadingError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    _imageError = new ImageEvent("imageError", -1, _imageStrings[_loadCounter]);
    dispatchEvent(_imageError);
}

private function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    _images.push(loader.data as ByteArray); // _images is an Array
    // I have also tried...
    // _images.push(ByteArray(loader.data));
}

public function get image():Array {
    return _images;
}
```

Then, from the game initialisation, I do this:

```
for (var loop:uint = 0; loop<_imageLoader.numImages; loop++) {
    planetTextures.push(context3D.createTexture(2048, 2048, Context3DTextureFormat.BGRA, false));
    planetTextures[planetTextures.length-1].uploadCompressedTextureFromByteArray(_imageLoader.image[loop], 0);
}
```

But I either get a null error on the 'uploadCompressedTextureFromByteArray' line or, if I use the 'ByteArray(loader.data)' option in my ImageLoader class Flash tells me the loaded data can't be coerced into a ByteArray. Any tips on how to pass loaded ATF data as a ByteArray for upload to the GPU?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing:

```
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
```

This is what causes the `.data` property to return a `ByteArray`.

Some more comments for your specific case:

- Be careful to remove the event listeners from loader or you'll get a memory leak.  You should have loader be a class variable and remove those listeners in both the `imageLoaded` handler and the `loadingError` handler.
- For maximum quality / efficiency, there is a tool called PVRTexTool that can create better quality / smaller compressed textures than `png2atf`.  I [wrote about it some in the starling forums](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/atf-observations-ymmv).
- You're probably already aware, but you didn't mention target platform and there are different compressed GPU texture formats for each as outlined in the [ATF introduction on adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashruntimes/articles/introducing-compressed-textures.html).  You'll need to use the appropriate encoding per target platform.  I found another answer where I [elaborated the png2atf commands per platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525398/1026023).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like that's got me a stage closer! It's now passing the data into the ByteArray; The error now is a decoding error. I figured it was something to do with the settings when I made the atfs - but now png2atf is crashing! I may look at that alternative you suggest but, for now at least, I think I'll file atfs under 'too much work for the pay off'.

Comment: They are a pain.  I added one more link (to an answer with some details on the atf format and a lot of png2atf examples), just in case you change your mind.  Good luck!